# how to stop this code from looping when specified. also how to get the finish button to show

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops

```
public void Game ()
{

    btnCheck.Visible = true;
    btnNext.Visible = true;
    c = ran.Next(0, 14);

    for (int i = 0; i < Global.choice; i++)
    {
        colour = englishColour[c];

        getColour();

        if (i == Global.choice)
        {

            btnFinish.Visible = true;
        }

    }
```

i am continually being asked the questions even when global.choices is specified as 1. finish button does not become visible. I want it to show when the specified amount of questions have been asked.

Comment: `i` will always be 1 lesser than `Global.choice` as per your `for` loop logic so are you looking for `i == Global.choice - 1`?

Comment: The code in the nested if is unreachable.

Comment: It's unreachable *unless* `getColour` is changing `Global.choice`. Don't do that. Don't use anything global or global-like. That invites "action at a distance" and it will bite you, often. Furthermore, using an input as a loop limit when it can change within the loop is rarely correct. You need to rethink your logic from the start.

Comment: this is a perfect debugging problem, set the `Global.choice` to 1 and step through the loop, have a look at how `i` changes, what values it takes and at which point in time this condition: `i < Global.choice` is evaluated

Comment: it is in another form that a user would select from a dropdown box how many questions they want 1-15

Comment: Then a larger reorganization is in order. The user input form needs to provide the selections to the parent form (as properties that the parent form reads), which in turn provides those values to whatever will use them (such as whatever's running this loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show the btnfinsh button, you can modify the for sentence.

Like the following code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i <=choice; i++) //  Change i< choice to i<=choice
            {
                //colour = englishColour[c];

                //getColour();

                if (i == choice)
                {

                    btnfinish.Visible = true;
                }
            }
```

Besides, I think there is no need to stop the loop when specified, because the

btnfinish can be shown when the loop in the last number.

Answer (score 0):

Your code cannot work since you loop from 0 until GlobalChoice-1.
But the

```
btnFinish.Visible = true;
```

just out of the loop and remove the if condition.